# Audio and video are out of sync

Tags: 11.10, pulseaudio, vlc, mplayer, audio-sync

I just upgraded to Oneiric Ocelot and a problem that was already present in Natty has become worse - namely, the audio and video are not in sync both in VLC and in mplayer. The problem only used to happen in VLC in Natty.

Some searching on the Internet seems to indicate that pulse-audio might be the problem.

Comment: I used to have this audio/video out of sync problem in 11.04 with VLC. I performed a clean install of 11.10 yesterday and to my delight the audio and video are perfectly synchronized in videos played with VLC. I would try completely reinstalling VLC to see if this problem was just "carried over".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about the problem that was Pulseaudio but that was solved in the 1.0 version of it which is the one that 11.10 is using. The other part of the problem is that you need the 1.1.12 version of VLC to make it work correctly with the new version of Pulseaudio. To do this add the following PPA (Which is the only one I have found so far with the 1.1.12):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/vlc`

then do `sudo apt-get update` to get the new updates. After that just update VLC to the new 1.1.12.

Tested today and all problems related to sync are gone. Should be mention that this is a PPA from a 3rd party source. So if you would like to wait for Ubuntu to update VLC officially you can do that to. For myself I won't go through another version of Ubuntu with the sync problem again.

**INFO** - https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/vlc?field.series_filter=oneiric

**UPDATE** - There is no more the need to add this PPA since in the main repositories the VLC version 1.1.12 has been added. After todays update to the 1.1.12 version of VLC and using Ubuntu 11.10. Most if not all out of sync problems are gone.

Users need to update their Ubuntu to the latest daily updates which should provide the latest version of VLC (the 1.1.12 version). Already tested and all movies I have seen are working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I followed this instructions and worked great:

http://www.st4ck.com/it/post/ubuntu-11-04-vlc-out-of-sync/#Runtime

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested changing the `Caching Value` under preferences ( `ctrl + p`, then `Show settings: all` )
[image]
If you are using NAS as your media storage you should change in the `SMB` `Access Module`.

Test setting it to 0 if you are reading the file from your HDD.

Comment: How do you open this window to set the Caching Value?