# Delayed sound in with Intel HD audio

Tags: 11.10, sound, intel

I have just upgraded from my Natty to Oneric and I am having a problem. The audio seems to be delayed compared to the video. It isn't just a bug in flash, 'cause the sound is delayed in every video that I've tried to play in computer. Does anybody know what to do?

My configuration includes *Intel i5 2500k and Asus P8H67-m EVO with Intel HD Audio*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Audio and video are out of sync](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66023/audio-and-video-are-out-of-sync)

Comment: Are the audio and video out of sync when you play video files on your PC?

Comment: I made a mistake in writting a post. Yes, the audio/video sync is bad in every video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which video player ?
VLC can have trouble with pulseaudio : setup vlc preferences to make him using alsa

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! But I also have a problem in Flashplayer.

Comment: I restarted computer and no more problem with flash. Thank you all